# Django - how to filter ManyToMany relations?

Tags: python, django, django-models

There is a `Translator` model in my project. This model has `ManyToManyField` `languages_verified` (verbose_name='users_languages_verified') and `languages_not_verified`. I want to get all `Language` objects which are at at least one `languages_verified` set.

So if translator x and y:

```
x.languages_verified = ['FR','EN']
x.languages_not_verified = ['RU','SK']
y.languages_verified = ['RU']
y.languages_not_verified = ['SK','CZ']
```

Then the output would be `['FR','EN','RU']` (not 'SK' nor 'CZ' because they are not in at least one languages_verified set)

It would be possible to do that for example this way:

```
lang_ver_set = []
for language in Language.objects.all():
    for translator in Translator.objects.all():
        if language in translator.languages_verified():
            lang_ver_set.append(language)
            break
```

But I'm not sure if this is a most efficient way how to do that. Django has many magic filter tricks like `verbose_name__in...` which could be probably faster but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the reverse relationship.

```
Language.objects.exclude(users_languages_verified=None)
```